# replacing LiveSDK signinbutton with custom button in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, single-sign-on, live-sdk

Is that possible to use a normal button control and ten load the Microsfot account signin page .  I was able to do this using the signin button provided by the lvie sdk though. But with normal button how do we do this ?

```
<liveControls:SignInButton Command="{Binding LiveAcntSessionChanged}"  Branding="MicrosoftAccount"
                                       Scopes="{Binding LiveScopeIds,Mode=OneTime}"  Height="70"
                                       ClientId="{Binding BClientId,Mode=OneTime}"  x:Name="btnLiveSignIn"
                                       TextType="Login" Content="Microsoft Account"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                       SessionChanged="btnLiveSignIn_SessionChanged" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below lines has fixed the issue

```
 if (loginResult.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
     loginResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.basic", "wl.offline_access", "wl.signin" });
```